# Does Visual Studio Code C++ Unit Test coverage?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

We have a C++ project we're developing on Linux with gcc. We'd like to use Visual Studio Code--if we can ever get it configured properly--but we can't if it won't meet our needs.

Does Visual Studio Code show C++ unit test coverage? For example, like how Eclipse shows code coverage of JUnit tests? Can it even be configured to run unit tests with Google Test, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code coverage reports seems to be [available only in real Visual Studio Enterprise edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested). For VS Code you can only utilize some command line utils, such as gcov.

Comment: the question mentions vscode in the title, the text and the tags and they mention linux. I'm pretty sure they're not talking about Visual Studio.

Comment: Right, I was asking about VS Code, but he did address it in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to [Gcov Viewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JacquesLucke.gcov-viewer) plugin for vscode. that
uses the output from gcc to Highlight the covered lines. and automate usage of e gcov .

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30185846)